# how do i run this .py code for a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

This code isnt mine btw. I was trying to code a discord bot for the heck of it, i did basic stuff like it will respond to certain pieces of text in a channel, but i wanted to add mod stuff bc why not, saw this and idk how to use the command

```
async def kick(ctx, userName: discord.User):
    if True: #ctx.message.author.Permissions.administrator
        await BSL.kick(userName)
    else:
        permission_error = str('Sorry ' + ctx.message.author + ' you do not have permissions 
to do that!')
        await BSL.send_message(ctx.message.channel, permission_error)
```

Comment: what is the issue? U wanna replace the true? understand something? there is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

To use a discord bot you need to go through a lot of steps. Here is the things you need to do to be able to run this script of yours:

- Go to the application page on discord, and click the "New Application" button.
- Give the application a name, and go to the "Bot" tab, and then click "Add Bot" button, then give your bot a name.
- Keep the default settings for Public Bot (checked) and Require OAuth2 Code Grant (unchecked).
- Click on the "Copy" button under Token, and store this in a text file somewhere on your computer. (This is the bot's password).
- Go to the "OAuth2" tab. Then select "bot" under the "scopes" section.
- Select the permissions that your bot needs. (Do not overdo it).
- Click on the "Copy" button, and paste this URL into a browser tab.
- Choose a server to invite the bot to, and click “Authorize” (To add the bot, your account needs "Manage Server" permissions)
- Install the `discord.py` library to access discord API, by running: `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`.
- Add these lines on top of your script for your bot:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
```

- And finally add `client.run(TOKEN)` to end on your script - where `TOKEN` is the token you copied earlier.
- Now that the bot is created and registered, you can simply type: `python3 main.py` to run it. (`main.py` can be something else, depending on what you named your bot file)

Comment: i understand how to use a bot, i already have it running and it works, i just dont know how to run the command.